# How to perform a count(*) as total on condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I would like to do a SQL query `count(*) as total` on a condition - If the http_response is equal to 0, then it should set the total value to 0, not 1 as it currently does.

```
http_response  created_at           session_id                  website_id

404            2018-03-03 17:20:18  2018-03-03 17:15:40-BaC-2   2
404            2018-03-03 17:20:18  2018-03-03 17:15:40-BaC-2   2
404            2018-03-03 17:20:18  2018-03-03 17:15:40-BaC-2   2
0              2018-02-27 14:21:14  2018-02-27 14:19:32-T6f-2   2
404            2018-02-28 14:21:14  2018-02-28 14:19:32-T6f-2   2
```

How my Laravel query looks(if really needed, I can try to get the raw SQL query equivalent for this query):

```
brokenlink::withTrashed()
                ->whereBetween('created_at', [$range['from'], $range['to']])
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                ->where('website_id', $website_id)
                ->select('created_at', DB::raw('count(*) as total')) 
                ->groupBy('session_id')
                ->get();
```

The outcome that I get :

```
03/03/2018 : 3
27/02/2018 : 1
28/02/2018 : 1
```

The desired outcome :

```
03/03/2018 : 3
27/02/2018 : 0
28/02/2018 : 1
```

Comment: I don't know Laravel, but you need to effectively change your `COUNT(*)` to something like `COUNT(CASE WHEN http_response = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END)`. Alternatively, you could use a `SUM` instead: `SUM(CASE WHEN http_response = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case-when`

```
 brokenlink::withTrashed()
 ...
 ->select('created_at', DB::raw('CASE WHEN http_response =0 THEN 0 ELSE count(*) END as total')) 
 ->groupBy('session_id')
 ->get();
```